# Why does `echo -e` not work when used with a variable?

Tags: bash, echo

```
#!/bin/bash
RESULT=$(ls)

echo -e "$RESULT"  # prints the result of 'ls' with new lines
echo -e $RESULT    # prints the result of 'ls' in one line
```

Why does the second approach print all in one line instead of a new line for each item ? Should'nt the `-e` option trigger the interpretation of the `\n` charachters ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run this command:

```
echo -e $RESULT
```

Bash performs [*word splitting*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting) on `$RESULT`; that is, it splits it up by whitespace, and passes the resulting tokens as separate arguments to `echo`. So you're essentially running this:

```
echo -e file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

and `echo` has no way of knowing that `$RESULT` contained newlines.

(The `-e`, by the way, isn't really relevant here. `-e` doesn't affect the treatment of newline characters, only of an actual sequence like `\n` — a backslash followed by an `n`.)

Answer (score 4):

`-e` is irrelevant.

`echo "$RESULT"` sees one parameter, a string with embedded newlines.

`echo $RESULT` sees as many parameters as there are words in `$RESULT`. The whitespace (including newlines) that separate these words is eaten by the shell.

Answer (score 0):

It's treating the different lines as separate arguments in this case.